# Why my injected mongoose models do not return documents when calling find()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a service module that saves and retrieves documents from a mongo collection in Mongo Atlas.

This service module is a thin wrapper around mongoose, and I'm injecting mongoose and its models through the constructor like this:

```
function ThinService(q, mongoose, models) {
  this.q = q;
  this.mongoose = mongoose;
  this.models = models;
}
```

I'm instantiating this `ThinService` from an express route, like this:

```
const q = require('q');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const querySchema = require('../lib/schemas/query.schema');
const qs = mongoose.Schema(querySchema);
const Query = mongoose.model('Query', qs);

const contactSchema = require('../lib/schemas/contact.schema');
const cs = mongoose.Schema(contactSchema);
const Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', cs);

let S = require('../lib/thin.service');
const thinService = new S(q, mongoose, {'Query': Query, 'Contact': Contact});
```

The next part is where the problems start to happen. My thin service has a method written like this:

```
ThinService.prototype.findByQuery({
  this.mongoose.connect(HOST);
  let deferred = this.q.defer();
  let db = this.mongoose.connection;
  db.on('error', (err) => {
    deferred.reject(err);
  });

  db.once('open', () => {
    this.models.Contact
    .find({query: query})
    .exec((err, contacts) => {
      if (err) {
        deferred.reject(err);
      }
      deferred.resolve(contacts);
    });
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that when I'm resolving that promise in my express route:

```
  queries = ['body fat', 'exercise', 'training tips'];

  let promisedQueries = queries.map((query) => {
    return S.findByQuery(query); // <-- this is where the odd behavior starts.
  });

  q.allSettled(promisedQueries)
  .then((result) => { 
    // result is always empty, although I know for a fact that there are documents that match my query.
    if (result) {
      res.send({
        id: 1,
        timestamp: Date.now(),
        result: result
      });
      return q();
    }
    // irrelevant else block
  })
```

The problem starts within the `then` block of `q.allSettled` because the promise's result is always empty. This shouldn't be the case because I know for a fact that there are documents that match my query.

So my first assumption is that there has to be something wrong with the way that I'm injecting my services/models. I'm using Mongo Compass to verify that my documents are being stored in the right collections, and upon inspecting the object the connection details are right too (database, collection, host, port, user/password, etc...)

A pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the query like? Could you possibly be querying `_id` as a string and not using MongoDB's `ObjectId`?

Comment: I fixed the problem by not connecting to mongo on every request. That literally solved the problem.